# C# shared code across multiple websites by moving code up a folder outside website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web

I have 3 differnt websites on same webserver under a root directory.  A lot of the code is the same across all 3 websites.

I wanted to see if there was a way to move code from all 3 websites up one level (outside the website itself) to the root directory (where the folders for each website are contained.

EX.  The root directory is c:\ (where i want to move the files to and access from each indivual website.  The websites themselves are contained in c:\Website1, c:\Website2, etc.

So is it possible to move code from c:\Website1 to c:\ and access it from c:\ in the c:\Website1 website?

If you need more details or I am not clear let me know.

Thank You.

Comment: Create a dll and put it in the GAC?

Comment: What about a well-designed BusinessLogic in a dll? (each WebSite could refer to this and call the same code..)

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz and reference it with relative paths that go up the needed amount of levels with "..\..\.."

Comment: I'd rather put it in the GAC and refer to it (add a reference within VS to this dll) see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182316/how-to-register-a-net-dll-in-gac) on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend putting the library DLL in the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx).

Consider this: what if you need to update the library DLL to support new features for one site, but this introduces incompatibilities with the other sites?  The GAC supports multiple versions of the same assembly, so you can update the web sites separately, if desired.

Comment: The problem with the dlls is we do not have access to the QA and PROD servers to register the DLL's on those machines.

So if we could just create a folder at c:\ called "SharedCode" or something and reference the .cs files and controls that would be great.

The dll would work for the .cs files but not for the controls (and a few other files that are not .cs files)

Comment: How do you update the QA and PROD servers with changes?  Do you have a setup program or other batch that installs the web site code?  If so, then the setup program or batch should have access to the GAC.

Comment: If you don't have access to those servers, it ought to be your responsibility to make an installer for your Prod/ QA maintainers that does the needed work, or to provide those people instructions on how to use [GACUTIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: We have a roll tool that was built so that we do not have access to the servers, but we can roll files from DEV (which we do have access to) to QA and then PROD.

Comment: Is it possible to modify that tool? It certainly seems justified in this case.

Comment: No the tool is a company wide tool, it is not anything we can modify

Comment: This doesnt work for what I want it to do, but answers my question for how to do it if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish placing them inside of a dll may make since. I would advice placing those in folder: `c:\libs\` and then you could access it via: `..\libs\`