# Batch Script that Installs dll to Assembly folder

Tags: batch-file, dll, gac

For some reason, our dev deployment is done by copying an updated `.dll` file to the GAC ([Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac)) by dragging and dropping it to the `C:\Windows\Assembly` folder.

I tried to create a batch script that contains the following code:

```
XCOPY d:\source\sample.dll c:\Windows\Assembly
```

but this seems to not work.

I was told it is because dragging the `.dll` into the `Assembly` folder does not copy it, but installs it somehow.

Is there a way to do this using a batch?

We do this 20 times per day, so its really time consuming to do this manually every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [gacutil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182316/how-to-register-a-net-dll-in-gac) it seems like a duplicate.
BTW: Assembly tag is for low-level assembler.

Comment: But gacutil is a visual studio command prompt right? can we do this with using the default command prompt?

Comment: You can use it with non-VS command prompt. Use full path to gacutil.exe i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe or setup environment PATH to that directory where gacutil.exe is located.

Comment: Tnx this saved me tons of hours. Really appreciate it bro :)