# Adding Windows Runtime Component (wraps Class library) in Windows 10 Cordova Project via cmd line by defining it custom plugin's xml doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, cordova, uwp, windows-10, cordova-plugins

I created a Windows universal project with cordova cmd line. (create a new project, added platform `windows`)

Built the project and run it from cmd line. Works fine.

My requirement is to create my own custom plugin and install it via npm cmd line.

My project also need to access native code with Windows Runtime Component.

I opened the above project **CordovaApp** in Visual Studio 2015.

Then I added a Windows Runtime Component also I added Newtonsoft library ([link here why I added Newtonsoft manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671641/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-9-0-0-0-culture-neutr)). I added a following Service class:

```
public sealed class Service
{
    public IAsyncOperation<string> Open(string param)
    {
        return OpenHelper(param).AsAsyncOperation();
    }
    private async Task<string> OpenHelper(string param)
    {
        try
        {
            JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(JArray.Parse(param)[0].ToString());
            string message = jObj["message"].ToString();
            return message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to add its dll or winmd file when installing my custom plugin via cmd line. So I copied my **.winmd** file from *bin\x86\MyRuntime.winmd* and place it inside my custom plugin folder *(\src\windows\lib)*.

My custom plugin.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="cordova-test-plugin"
    version="0.1.0">
    <name>Launcher</name>
    <description>PhoneGap  Plugin</description>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords>phonegap,launcher</keywords>

  <js-module src="www/launcher.js" name="Launcher">
    <clobbers target="window.launcher" />
  </js-module>

  <!-- windows -->
  <platform name="windows">

  <js-module src="src/windows/Launcher.js" name="LauncherProxy">
      <merges target="" />
    </js-module>
 <framework src="src/windows/lib/MyRuntime.winmd" custom="true" />
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

I have **launcher.js** file in my cordova plugin from where native runtime component is called like below:

**Launcher.js**

```
  cordova.commandProxy.add("LauncherProxy", {
    open: function(successCallback, errorCallback, pluginParam) {
        var service = MyRuntime.Service();
        service.open(JSON.stringify(pluginParam)).then(function(data) {
            successCallback(data);
        });
    }
});
require("cordova/exec/proxy").add("Launcher", module.exports);
```

In my **index.js**, I have this method call on device ready event:

```
launcher.openFile(function (message) {
    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message).showAsync();
    console.log(message);
}, function () {

});
```

FYI: Also launcher.js inside the **\www** of my custom plugin has following code structure:

```
cordova.define("cordova-test-plugin.Launcher", function(require, exports, module) {
    var objWindowsLauncher = {
        openFile: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
            cordova.exec(
                successCallback,
                errorCallback,
                'LauncherProxy',
                'open',
                [{
                    "message": "Hello test message"
                }]
            );
        }
    }
    module.exports = objWindowsLauncher;
    });
```

Till now it works well. It pop up's `Hello test message` when app is run.

Now I added a new Class library project for SQLite. Installed sqlite-net (include SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs files from old project), added Newtonsoft.json dll, SQlite for Universal Windows Platform, Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platfrom.

Added this SQLite reference (Class library) to my previous Runtime Component project by right clicking on the Reference and selecting SQLite project.
By doing this, now I can do sqlite operation in runtime component. I build this runtime component and hence its new **.winmd** file is generated inside *bin\x86\Debug*. I copied this winmd file and place it inside my custom plugin folder like above.

I removed the plugin and re-added the plugin (cmd line installation) just like above. This time also, the project should work same as previous, but doesn't work.

It throws an exception.
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`
`at MyRuntime.Service.<OpenHelper>d__1.MoveNext()`
`at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder 1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)`

**Another case:**

Sometimes, I get this exception with the exact above process:
`Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies`

**INFO**

All the project build configuration is under x86.

Newtonsoft version is: 9.0.1, 10.x.x

Cordova Windows 10 project, Runtime Component and Class Library has: 10.0.14393.0 (Target Version) and 10.0.10240.0 (Min Version)

Cordova version: 7.0.1
Cordova Windows version: 5.0.0

**Plugin installation and remove cmd:**

*cordova plugin remove cordova-test-plugin*

*cordova plugin add ..\plugins\cordova-test-plugin*

I have shared the complete project with custom plugin here in [onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtaerMmEJshDi91rGn7MLo4coNArsw).

P.S. I can add the Runtime component reference manually and make it work but I want to do with cmd line interface, install pluigns, build and generate packages from cmd line interface without interacting with Visual Studio.

Please let me know your views, I remember when I started to work few months back, it used to work. (adding reference from cmd line by defining **.winmd** file in plugin.xml (`<framework src="src/windows/lib/MyRuntime.winmd" custom="true" />`)). It used to work fine. But recently I'm facing above problem.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried as @Elvis Xia suggested. This seems to load the runtime component as expected. I included all these: 
    `<framework src="src/windows/lib/SQLite.dll" custom="true"/>
    <framework src="src/windows/lib/MyRuntime.winmd" custom="true" />
    <framework src="src/windows/lib/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" custom="true"/>`

in my plugin.xml and installed the plugin via cmd line. There is still some bug while creating SQLite database. I faced `system.dllnotfoundexception unable to load dll 'sqlite3'` error as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `SQLite.dll` and `NewtonJson.dll` should also be added as reference in your plugin. So your plugin.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="cordova-test-plugin"
    version="0.1.0">
    <name>Launcher</name>
    <description>PhoneGap  Plugin</description>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords>phonegap,launcher</keywords>

 <js-module src="www/launcher.js" name="Launcher">
    <clobbers target="window.launcher" />
  </js-module>

  <!-- windows -->
  <platform name="windows">

  <js-module src="src/windows/Launcher.js" name="LauncherProxy">
      <merges target="" />
    </js-module>

  <!--   <framework src="src/windows/lib/MyRuntime.winmd" custom="true" /> -->
    <framework src="src/windows/lib/SQLite.dll" custom="true"/>
    <framework src="src/windows/lib/MyRuntime.winmd" custom="true" />
    <framework src="src/windows/lib/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" custom="true"/>
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

And copy `SQLite.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` under `bin\x86\debug\` folder to your plugin's `src/windows/lib/`. Then it will works fine.

Comment: Hi Elvis, Can you please let me know where can I find SQLite.dll file?

Comment: It's the same folder where you get the MyRuntime.winmd.

Comment: Hi @Elvis Xia, I have tried as you suggested. included all those dlls in my plugin.xml file. It seems to load Runtime component methods and also Newtonsoft.dll,  but still I get `system.dllnotfoundexception unable to load dll 'sqlite3'` while the database is being created. i have added "Update 1 " in my question above. Am I still missing something to include in my plugin.xml file?

Comment: I don't know which SQLite Library you are currently using, but it obviously rely on `sqlite3.dll`. You will need to find that `dll` too and add it as framework in your `plugin.xml`.

Comment: I'm using `sqlite-net` by Frank Krueger (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).