# C# .net windows forms; upload image with cloudinary through picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, cloudinary

*First of all, I'm new to .net/C#*

I want the user to pick an image through a picturebox and the image should upload directly to [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_integration).

```
public static Cloudinary cloudinary;

public const string CLOUD_NAME = "XXXXXX";
public const string API_KEY = "XXXXXXX";
public const string API_SECRET = "XXXXXX";

string imagePath = "";
static void cloudinaryAccount(string[] args)
{
    Account account = new Account(CLOUD_NAME, API_KEY, API_SECRET);
    cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "All files(*.*)|*.*";
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        imagePath = dialog.FileName.ToString();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imagePath;
    }
    uploadImage(imagePath); // pass the path of the image to the uploadImage() function.
}

public static void uploadImage(string imagePath)
{

    var UploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
    {
        File = new FileDescription(imagePath)
    };


    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(UploadParams);
}
```

But when it comes to the `cloudinary.Upload(UploadParams)` it throws

[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpo0t.png)

So it's probably because it `cloudinary` is null.
So if I move

```
Account account = new Account(CLOUD_NAME, API_KEY, API_SECRET);
cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);
```

into the `uploadImage(string imagePath)` function, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671641/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-9-0-0-0-culture-neutr) and fixed it, it's working now.

Comment: Use your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the following line is run before the call to `upload`:

```
cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);
```

Comment: I did, after that I get this error: _System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'_