# NuGet package breaks with "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard, vsix

I've NuGet package (.Net Standard 2.0) that references `Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.1` by PackageReference (What's called the new way). All looks good when packing it. Installing in the VSIX project shows that `Newtonsoft` will be downloaded as well and builds successfully. The error happens when VSIX project (.Net Full 4.8) runs and the method that uses Newtonsoft breaks with the message `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.JSON, Version=13.0.0.0, ...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I've tried different approaches (none of them worked):

- Manually copying `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` to libs folder in downloaded package.
- Forcing installing `Newtonsoft.JSON` in the VSIX project.

The NuGet project can be found [here](https://github.com/wakatime/nuget-wakatime-shared-extension-utils/tree/major/wakatime-cli-go) and the VSIX project [here](https://github.com/wakatime/visualstudio-wakatime/tree/feature/update-nuget).

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I've changed from `Newtonsoft` to `System.Text.Json` to give a try and the error didn't change.

Comment: I found a previous post similar to your situation as attached. Try the approaches suggested there? Good luck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671641/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-9-0-0-0-culture-neutr/38715898#38715898

Comment: @JacquiHuang I've added the source code for the NuGet package as well the VSIX project.

Answer (score 0):

So from the error message, the issue is that the NuGet package, related files or dependencies cannot be found/loaded. So the cause should be the specific NuGet package does not exist, or is not located in the specific folder/directory, or the path is not pointed out. Or there are several different versions of the same NuGet packages used by mixed.

Since not sure of your project/solution structure, I assume you have a .net standard based project, and you packed it into a NuGet package. Also you installed it in a VSIX project, and in this VSIX project, you used the method from Newtonsoft.json NuGet package which is referenced in your .net standard project.

**First thing** you can try is manually copy the **correct version** of Newtonsoft.Json.dll(normally in `C:\Users\[user name]\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\13.0.1\lib\...`) into your VSIX project folder. The VSIX project folder directory should be like this `XXXX\XXXX\[your project folder name]\bin\Debug(or Release, depend on which mode you are using)`.

**Other suggestions:**

Go to Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > click and check `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` and `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio` checkboxes, and then click `Clear All NuGet Cache(s)` button > OK. After that rebuild and rerun your VSIX project.

If above don’t work, could you please share some steps with me to reproduce your issue and check further :)

Comment: I've added the source code for the NuGet package as well the VSIX project.

Comment: I could successfully run the VSIX project that you shared. Looks like there is no issue with your codes/settings, and perhaps cache affect? Have you tried to run your VSIX project on another machine? Besides, please clear NuGet cache and project cache(`bin`, `obj`, `.vs` folders). Also [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#how-to-repair).