# SharePoint-SQL connection System.ArgumentNullException: The value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#, sql-server, cookies, sharepoint, ssis

I'm trying to implement this project in order to get information from a SharePoint List and insert it into a SQL Table:

- [Load data to a SQL table from sharepoint list using SSIS Part One](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/load-data-to-a-sql-table-from-sharepoint-list-using-ssis-part-one/)
- [Load data to a SQL table from sharepoint list using SSIS Part Two](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/load-data-to-a-sql-table-from-sharepoint-list-using-ssis-part-two/) ←
- [Load data to a SQL table from sharepoint list using SSIS Part Three](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/load-data-to-a-sql-table-from-sharepoint-list-using-ssis-part-three/)

I'm stuck on part two (arrow one).
I cannot get the Authentification Cookies using the *SharePointInlineCredential.GetAuthenticationCookie method*:

[image]

> System.ArgumentNullException: The value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

What I have done:

- At first I was having a problem similar to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8048396f-d942-4c83-af66-ef3f88454652/error-when-adding-a-remote-event-receiver-to-my-sharepoint-addin-quotcould-not-load-file-or?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)  when I try to run the project , but I could fix it by installing *SharePoint Online Client Components SDK* and by referencing all `.dll` packages to the instalation route of this SDK.
- Also I installed the same `.dll` packages in GAC ( by following [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182316/how-do-i-register-a-net-dll-file-in-the-gac) ), because the references via NuGet weren't being saved.
- I tried to make a direct connection to the Sharepoint site using this [reference](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-odata-ssis-connection-for-sharepoint-online/), but after double-checking steps above, the error still persists.

> The connection could not be verified > The value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

[image]

- Additionally I tried reconfiguring the SharePoint site as shown in this [article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211401/error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-nameg-in-sharepoint-2013), enabling *SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure* and the *SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure*, but nothing got better.
- Also I changed the SecurityProtocol Type to all of below:

[image]

I had already double-checked:

- User name that goes as follows: *username@companydomain.com*
- URL site that goes as *https://companydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME/*
- Correct Password

Error detail:

```
The exception was originally thrown on this call stack:
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.FindEntry(TKey)
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.MapPartnerSoapFault(string)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetSoapException(System.Xml.Linq.XDocument)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.HandleWebException(System.Net.WebException)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.DoPost(string, string, string, System.Func<System.Net.WebException, System.Exception>)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetPartnerTicketFromAdfs(string, string, string)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetServiceToken(string, string, string, string)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(System.Uri, string, System.Security.SecureString)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(System.Uri, bool)
    ...
    [Pila de llamadas truncada]
```

Additional details:

Whenever a person authenticates in Office365 a pop-up window appears redirecting to the company site so there you can put your credentials, I don't know if that has something to do here.
I am the owner of the site.

What am I doing wrong?